# Change a site column type from “Enhanced Rich Text” to “Rich Text”, will corrupt the data . even if we do not already have images and tables

Tags: 2013, list, development, rich-text

I have an issue tracking list , and I chose to have the Description field as “Enhanced Rich Text” field, then I added a test content using text and bullets only.
Then we decide to not allow users to insert images or tables inside the field, so I simple went to the list setting and the changed the column type at list level to be “Rich Text” instead of “Enhanced Rich Text”, as follow:-

[image]

But after doing so, I get the description field showing “View Entries” instead of showing the old text..,, as follow:-

[image]

So can anyone advice what is causing this problem and how I can overcome it,,, or at-least to return the old data as it was?. and as I said although we use to have “Enhanced Rich Text” field but we only added text and bullets,, so I though it is safe to changed it to “Rich Text”or at-least I though the images will be removed,, but what is the status now ,, and what does “Show Entries ” means , and even if I return the type back as “Enhanced Rich Text”, will not solve the problem?

Can anyone advice on this please?

Comment: You may need to restore from a backup to be honest. When you changed that, it changed the HTML into the rendered view. You may be able to get by with a powershell script, but that will have to take some research

Comment: so why SP will allow to do such a type change , then it will not support the result... so strange ,, whenever i do any thing inside SharePoint i realize how it is unstructured and have full of bugs. so now it will allow you to chnage from Enhanced rich Text to Rich Text but the normal text and bullets will no more show,,,,,and even if i chnage the type back to Enhanced Rixh Text nothing will chnage...

Comment: It probably gave you a warning saying that "are you sure you want to change this field? It will change this column for all items in the list" and also if you see that "View Entries" beforehand was enhanced field, why change it? What were you trying to do?

Comment: The scenario is as follow, when i first create the list i chnage the "Description" field to be of type "Enhanced Rich Text". then i added some text content,, which only include text and bullets. but after that we review the fields and we decide to not allow users to add images or any enhanced rich text feature. so i went to the list column named "Description" and i chose to change it back to "Rich Text".

Comment: Since we only added text and bullets, so i tough that changing it back to Rich Text will not cause any problem, or atleast if we already have images then the worst case will be that the images will no longer be avilable... but the problem is that the Description text was replaced by a link named "View Entries" !!

Comment: Take a look at this. It may be because it's trying to act like a link still but rich text doesn't support links. The data may still be there, you just need to edit it in SharePoint Designer: http://www.manageprojectsonsharepoint.com/blog/2014/07/25/show-content-sharepoint-2013-append-rtf-column-view/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18450/discussion-between-mike-and-john-g).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its showing "View Entries" because you have "Append Changes to Text" turned on. Because of this for any update that is made to an item a new version is getting created.

Comment: so if i edit the column again and i chose Not to Append Changes To Text,, should i be able to get the old data ?

Comment: Actually i did this , i changed the column back to "Rich Text" , and i chose not to "Append Changes To Text", and now i can see the old data instead of "View entries" link. but could i be facing additional problems i am unaware of. or since i get the data back , everything should be fine  . can u advice please?

Comment: Since you go the data back I think you are fine. Before making such changes always backup the data so you can roll back in case of emergency.